# Show orthonormal system is an orthonormal basis

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having some issues with an exercise in my real analysis class. The exercise goes like this:

Let $\{e_{k}\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ be an orthonormal system in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$. Show that if

$$C_{c}(\mathbb{R})\subset \overline{\text{span}\{e_{k}\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}},$$

then $\{e_{k}\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ is an orthonormal basis for $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$.

Here's what my idea is:

I know that $C_{c}(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ which means $\overline{C_{c}(\mathbb{R})}=L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ and thus $C_{c}(\mathbb{R})\subset L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$.

Furthermore, if we have a basis $\{\tilde{e}_{k}\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ then I know that

$$\overline{\text{span}\{\tilde{e}_{k}\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}}=L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$$

So if I know that $C_{c}(\mathbb{R})\subset \overline{\text{span}\{e_{k}\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}}$, then $\{e_{k}\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ must be an orthonormal basis in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$, since if it wasn't the case, then $\{e_{k}\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ won't span all of $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ and thus $C_{c}(\mathbb{R})\subset \overline{\text{span}\{e_{k}\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}}$ won't hold.

My problem is that I don't know whether this is correct and also if it is, I feel like it is a vague argument, but I don't really know what else to do. Any help/hints are highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you define $C_c$?

Comment: Sure! $C_{c}(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of all continuous functions with compact support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct. If you want it more distilled, you could say:

$C_{c}(\mathbb{R})\subset \overline{\text{span}\{e_{k}\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}}$ implies $\overline{C_{c}(\mathbb{R})}\subset \overline{\text{span}\{e_{k}\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}}$ (smallest closed set containing $C_{c}(\mathbb{R})$)

Now note that we have $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})= \overline{C_{c}(\mathbb{R})}\subset \overline{\text{span}\{e_{k}\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}}\subset L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ and thus $\overline{\text{span}\{e_{k}\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}}= L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$, so $\{e_{k}\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ is an orthonormal basis for $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Thank you for the response! It is starting to make sense. But one question I do have: is it okay to just use $\subset$ and not $\subseteq$? Because how do we know that $\overline{\text{span}\{e_{k}\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}}\subset L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: @James You're very welcome. I consider $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ as synonyms (subset), but if you want to use $\subset$ as a proper subset (a more "official" notation would be $\subsetneq$), then you would indeed get $\overline{C_{c}(\mathbb{R})}\subseteq \overline{\text{span}\{e_{k}\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}}\subseteq L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$.